# Which local planner should i use for dynamic obstacles?

Tags: ros, planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We are currently using teb_local_planner bit it doesn't work for dynamic obstacles in the bots path... in th cost map a dynamic obstacle is perceived as a wall ...i think  .
Is there any other local planner which can be used for moving around dynamic obstacles??thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236497/which-local-planner-should-i-use-for-dynamic-obstacles?/) by [rajnunes](https://answers.ros.org/users/26472/rajnunes/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2016-06-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**EDIT**: The [teb_local_planner](http://wiki.ros.org/teb_local_planner) package has now support for dynamic obstacles based on a constant velocity model.
You can find two new tutorials on that topic in the [tutorials section](http://wiki.ros.org/teb_local_planner/Tutorials).

The navigation stack currently does not support dynamic obstacles actually. However, dynamic obstacles are treated as static in the current control/sampling interval. Due to the discretized grid representation of the costmap any temporal coherence isn't capured. However, extending the DWA or teb_local_planner to dynamic obstacles is in principal straight forward, but it would require additional tracking and motion prediction on top of the costmap.
Up to my knowledge, there isn't any local planner for the navigation stack that performs it's own tracking and prediction.
I am not aware of other planning packages beside of the navigation stack.

However, you can improve the current obstacle avoidance behavior by adding the inflation layer to the local costmap (in addition to the global costmap). By doing so, the robot starts earlier avoiding the obstalce (w.r.t. the static snapshot).
Currently, the teb_local_planner does not take inflated cells into account. In that case, refer to the DWA planner.
A concept similar to the original inflation has already been implemented in the teb_local_planner package

There are multiple other questions here with similar concerns:

- [Question 1](http://answers.ros.org/question/170376/navigation-combine-static_map-with-dynamic-obstacle-detection/)
- [Question 2](http://answers.ros.org/question/209105/represent-dynamic-obstacles-in-a-map/)
- [Question 3](http://answers.ros.org/question/235472/detect-dynamic-obstacles/)
- [Question 4](http://answers.ros.org/question/220058/dynamic-obstacle-problems-with-short-range-sensor/)
- [Questoin 5](http://answers.ros.org/question/221566/static_map-and-dynamic-obstacles/)
- [Question 6](http://answers.ros.org/question/194740/problem-with-obstacle-avoidance-and-the-local-planner/)

---

Originally posted by [croesmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/12166/croesmann/) with karma: 2531 on 2016-06-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kiwa21](https://answers.ros.org/users/27848/kiwa21/) on 2017-05-08**:
@croesmann Can you shade new light on this issue ? I've seen you've made a lot of upgrade to TEB since this was posted last year. Are there now some differences with what you commented above ? Thanks a lot!

**Comment by [croesmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/12166/croesmann/) on 2017-05-08**:
yeah, there were some updates, but I am going to push the dynamic obstacle update in june or july ;-)

**Comment by [howardcochran](https://answers.ros.org/users/28150/howardcochran/) on 2017-06-02**:
@croesmann, Can you commit a preview of dynamic obstacle handling for teb_local_planner (perhaps in a task branch)?  I am very interested in reading the code now and possibly contributing.

**Comment by [merlinwu](https://answers.ros.org/users/30646/merlinwu/) on 2017-06-05**:
@croesmann, Can you share some ideas about how to handle with dynamic obstacles like persons in the crowd in local planner? Thanks

**Comment by [croesmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/12166/croesmann/) on 2018-01-02**:
the dynamic obstacles extension is already in the public branch for quite some weeks now. Unfortunately, I had not enough spare-time yet to write a tutorial.